# Speed-up eigen c++ transpose?

Tags: c++, performance, linear-algebra, eigen, transpose

I know that this 'eigen speed-up' questions arise regularly but after reading many of them and trying several flags I cannot get a better time with c++ eigen comparing with the traditional way of performing a transpose. Actually using blocking is much more efficient. The following is the code

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Dense>

#define min( a, b ) ( ((a) < (b)) ? (a) : (b) )

int main(){
    const int n = 10000;
    const int csize = 32;
    float **a, **b;
    clock_t cputime1, cputime2;
    int i,j,k,ii,jj,kk;
  
    // Allocating memory for array/matrix
    a = new float * [n];
    for (i=0; i<n; i++){
        a[i] = new float [n];
    }
    b = new float * [n];
    for (i=0; i<n; i++){
        b[i] = new float[n];
    }
    // eigen matrices
    Eigen::MatrixXf M1 = Eigen::MatrixXf::Constant(n, n, 0.0);
    Eigen::MatrixXf M2 = Eigen::MatrixXf::Constant(n, n, 0.0);
    
    // Filling matrices with zeros
    for(i=0; i<n; ++i)
        for (j=0; j<n; ++j)
            a[i][j] = 0;
    for(i=0; i<n; ++i)
        for (j=0; j<n; ++j)
            b[i][j] = 0;

    // Direct (inefficient) transposition
    cputime1 = clock();
    for (i=0; i<n; ++i)
        for (j=0; j<n; ++j)
            a[i][j] = b[j][i];
    cputime2 = clock() - cputime1;
    std::printf("Time for transposition: %f\n", ((double)cputime2)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

    // Transposition using cache-blocking
    cputime1 = clock();
    for (ii=0; ii<n; ii+=csize)
        for (jj=0; jj<n; jj+=csize)
            for (i=ii; i<min(n,ii+csize-1); ++i)
                for (j=jj; j<min(n,jj+csize-1); ++j)
                    a[i][j] = b[j][i];
    cputime2 = clock() - cputime1;
    std::printf("Time for transposition: %f\n", ((double)cputime2)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

    // eigen
    cputime1 = clock();
    M1.noalias() = M2.transpose();
    cputime2 = clock() - cputime1;
    std::printf("Time for transposition with eigen: %f\n", ((double)cputime2)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

    // use data
    std::cout << a[n/2][n/2] << std::endl;
    std::cout << b[n/2][n/2] << std::endl;
    std::cout << M1(n/2,n/2) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

And the compiling command I am using is

```
g++ -fno-math-errno -ffast-math -march=native -fopenmp -O2 -msse2 -DNDEBUG  blocking_and_eigen.cpp
```

with results

```
Time for transposition: 1.926674
Time for transposition: 0.280653
Time for transposition with eigen: 2.018217
```

I am using eigen 3.4.0, and g++ 11.2.0.

Do you have any suggestion to improve eigen performance?
Thanks in advance

Comment: m2.transpose().eval(); ?

Comment: Maybe you should try `transposeInPlace` (see warning) https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1DenseBase.html#ac8952c19644a4ac7e41bea45c19b909c

Also maybe the copy to M1 is causing the performance drop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by INS in the comment is the actual copying of the matrix causing the performance drop, I slightly modify your example to use some numbers instead of all zeros (to avoid any type of optimisation):

```
for(i=0; i<n; ++i) {
    for (j=0; j<n; ++j) {
        a[i][j] = i+j;
        M1(i,j) = i+j;
      }
}
for(i=0; i<n; ++i) {
    for (j=0; j<n; ++j) {
        b[i][j] = i+j;
        M1(i,j) = i+j;
    }
}
```

Also, I modify the final printing statement with a full check over the result (when not in place the check will be performed against M2):

```
    for (i=0; i<n; ++i)
    for (j=0; j<n; ++j)
      if (a[i][j] != M1(i,j))
        std::cout << "Diff here! " << std::endl;
```

Then I tried several tests:

1. Preallocation and assignment

   Eigen::MatrixXf M2 = Eigen::MatrixXf::Constant(n, n, 0.0);
   ... some code here ...
   M2 = M1.transpose();
2. Copy constructor

   Eigen::MatrixXf M2(M1.transpose());
3. in place

   M1.transposeInPlace();
4. copy construct using auto and c++17

   auto M2{ M1.transpose() };

This is the most puzzling, the performance are outstanding, I think there are two part in the story, if I print the typeid name of M2 for case 2 and 4 they are different, and the name is mangled but it give us a clue:

N5**Eigen**6**Matrix**IfLin1ELin1ELi0ELin1ELin1EEE
N5**Eigen**9**Transpose**INS_6**Matrix**IfLin1ELin1ELi0ELin1ELin1EEEEE

auto keyword resolve to a different type specific for transpose matrix. The second part of the story is the fact that M1 is not modify afterwards, so either the compiler moves it or, most likely the EigenTransposeMatrix (https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1Transpose.html) is only keeping a reference of the original matrix and it doesn't copy it.

**Results**

| Test | Direct (s) | Cache block (s) | eigen (s) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2.633 | 0.312 | 1.861 |
| 2 | 2.599 | 0.262 | 1.968 |
| 3 | 2.602 | 0.262 | 0.216 |
| 4 | 2.552 | 0.280 | 0.000002 |

Comment: Thanks a lot for this study. Yes, it seems that the copy is the culprit. But removing it breaks the analogy with the primitive arrays example. I will play with the 4th example . I want to keep the analogy since in this code I am trying to highlight to some students the advantage of using numerical libraries instead of doing all matrix operations by hand. Thanks again.

Comment: @iluvatar in fairness, the array is pre-allocated, this seems a pretty convincing argument to use the library, point 3 is quicker then the hand made algorithm and point 4 is spectacularly quicker. But the main selling point for any numerical libraries is always correctness. Furthermore, the hand made array of arrays needs clean-up codes to avoid leaks (essential in any real-life application) and they library don't.

Comment: Test 4 does not do any actual work, though (`Eigen::Transpose<Eigen::Matrix<float,...> >` is an expression template, the actual work happens when assigning to another matrix)

Comment: Hi, just for completeness, and following @chtz comment, the expression template was actually doing nothing and that explained its extremely  small time. At the end, what I did was to implement a function that checked if the transposition was correct, therefore using the matrices. When I put that in the blocking and eigen times, and compiled with -O3, eigen was the fastest but with reasonable times (half or third of blocking). It is important to compile with -O3, otherwise eigen is the slowest by an order of magnitude.